# How to customize ASP.NET Websevices SOAP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

I need a SOAP webservice can receive quest like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:vas=" http://vasgate.mobifone.vn ">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <vas:register>
     <msisdn>904919419</msisdn>
     <packagecode>PACK1</packagecode>
     <username>kenh1</username>
     <password>kenh@123</password>
     <channel>wapportal</channel>
     <info>khuyenmai</info>
  </vas:register>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And can response like

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body >
  <ns2: registerResponse xmlns:ns2="http://vasgate.mobifone.vn" >
     <return>
       <returncode>1</ returncode >
       <returndesc>DANG_KY_THANH_CONG</returndesc>
       <package>
         <packagecode>PACK1</packagecode>
         <cycle>1</cycle>
         <price>1000</price>
         <desc>sample package1</desc>
       </package>
     </return>
  </ns2:registerResponse>
```

How to customize my webservice to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [Servicestack](http://servicestack.net). Highly flexible and way easier than WCF.

Comment: Thank, but this not is a answer

Comment: Request format is resolve but respose is not. Any one can help me